# How to define unique value in union if two rows are not same data

Tags: sql

I'm creating a simple SQL query with `union`, the result is returned correctly, but how to set a default value in a dummy column if the union result has two rows for one value?

If the result returned two values for one employee, then the dummy column is 'N' for the first value and 'Y' for the second value.

And if the result returned only one value for the employee, then the dummy column is 'Y'

How to achieve that?

[image: Screenshot as example]

This is the query that I'm using

```
select 
    dbo.employee,
    dbo.starting_date 
from 
    table_1
union
select 
    dbo.employee,
    dbo.hiring_date 
from 
    table_2
```

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What do you mean by "first" value?  By the date or by which table the value comes from?

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "quere" ....

Answer (score 1):

With a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select dbo.employee, dbo.starting_date date from table_1
  union all
  select dbo.employee, dbo.hiring_date date from table_2
)

select
  t.*,
  case when exists (
    select 1 from cte 
    where employee = t.employee and date > t.date 
  ) then 'N' else 'Y' end dummycolumn
from cte t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select t.employee, t.date,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by t.employee order by t.date)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as dummy
from ((select t1.employee, t1.starting_date as date
       from table_1 t1
      ) union all
      (select t2.employee, t2.starting_date as date
       from table_2 t2
      )
     ) t
```